# Other awesome topology related videos like this one?

Tags: general-topology

Turning a sphere inside-out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVVfs4zKrgk

And part 2: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7d13SgqUXg

This is really, really cool. They describe things in really simple terms though (like referring to curvatures with smiles and frowns) and sometimes I wish I could connect it to the math that I know if relevant terms were brought up. The animations are simply amazing, and I can't believe this was made in **1994**!

I was wondering if anyone knows if these people made other videos like this using their techniques... So cool!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/list-of-interesting-math-videos-documentaries - videos for Mobius transformations, origami, the Poincare conjecture, and some other geometrically flavored topics.

Comment: I have converted the question to [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741), as it's asking for a list of examples and there is no single right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [Math Overflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1714/best-online-math-videos)! For instance, you may enjoy this video about the [Möbius band](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY).

Answer (score 2):

Niles Johnson at UGA recently posted this video he made illustrating the Hopf fibration: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKotMPGFJYk