# Documentary of mathematics.

Tags: math-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of Interesting Math Videos/ Documentaries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/list-of-interesting-math-videos-documentaries)

I just watched a documentary of Fermat's last theorem. It is so good. I can feel how mathematician think and get excited.

It motivates me to study more and eventually try to solve a good problem.
Is there other mathematics documentary like this? Could you suggest one with URL? I prefer Youtube or other free sites.

Comment: Where can I see this documentary you talked about? I read the book related and I liked very much!

Comment: @chessmath http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FnXgprKgSE

Comment: That's what I watched.

Comment: @williamdemeo I can't watch the video in the link. It says "The URL contained a malformed video ID".

Comment: [This](http://www.webofstories.com/) link was shared on Google+ by someone I cannot remember. This has short "self-told" stories from the Life of many celebrities including Mathematicians. Hope you find it interesting. =)

Comment: [_Chaos: A Mathematical Adventure_](http://www.chaos-math.org/) (2010) and [_Dimensions_](http://www.dimensions-math.org/) (2008) by Jos Leys, Étienne Ghys, Aurélien Alvarez, et al. are excellent, [CC BY-NC-ND 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/deed.en)-licensed (i.e., free) movies about math.

Answer (score 4):

BBC's [The Story of Maths](http://youtu.be/i9x4cTJ18is) is a four part series outlining various aspects of the history of math.

See [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Maths) for a synopsis.

Answer (score 2):

The Code, by Marcus du Sautoy.

This is a nice, 3 part documentary about how mathematics can be used to describe the world around us. It's not particularly historical, but I'm sure you'll enjoy it; there's a lot of interesting examples in there that I hadn't seen before.

You can find the 3 parts on youtube (though I'm not 110% sure of the legality of this...), just search for something like 'The code Marcus du Sautoy'.

Comment: Completely agree with tom. The Code is very nice, however it contained some coincidence contents with the film "The Story of Math". which was mentioned by williamdemeo in the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can search on the webpage of Zala film :
http://zalafilms.com/index.html, there are many mathematical films for example, the documentary about Paul Hamos : "**I want to be a mathematician**", **Julian Robinson and the 10th problem of Hilbert**, **A Beautiful Mind**(film about John Nash).....

There are more documentaries by BBC, however they are about physics, you can browse the webpage of BBC Horizons. They are also very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

On [this site](http://www.cosmolearning.com/mathematics/documentaries/) you can find various mathematics documentaries (mostly BBC production)