# Documentaries about mathematics and mathematicians

Tags: soft-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of Interesting Math Videos/ Documentaries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/list-of-interesting-math-videos-documentaries)

I have watched "Fermat's last theorem" a documentary about  Andrew Wiles proof of the theorem, it was a great show. and i am asking if there is some other good documentaries about mathematics and mathematicians out there (not movies).

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of Interesting Math Videos/ Documentaries](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/list-of-interesting-math-videos-documentaries) (and also of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111159/documentary-of-mathematics which was closed as a duplicate.  Evidently a popular topic!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would definitely recommend "N is a NUMBER". I enjoyed it immensely as a portrayal of the curious and fascinating life of Paul Erdős.

Answer (score 4):

I liked documentary named "Dangerous Knowledge" about four brilliant mathematicians – Georg Cantor, Ludwig Boltzmann, Kurt Gödel and Alan Turing.

Comment: [link](http://www.dnatube.com/video/6065/BBCDangerous-Knowledge-Part-110)