# CINEMA : Mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, mathematicians

I know that a similar question has been asked about mathematics documentaries in general, but I would like some recommendations on films specifically about various mathematicians (male and or female).

---

What would be nice is if you'd recommend something about not just the famous ones but also the not so famous ones.

---

Note$_1$: If you happen to find a film on a transgender mathematician, well that's just great too. I'm a very progressive person with a very open brain.

---

Note$_2$: Throughout my life I've seen most of the mainstream films, but it'd be nice to hear from the world what things I may have missed.

---

Note$_3$: If you have the ability to search Nets outside of the the limitations of Google's Nets, then maybe you'll find some foreign films or something, as, for example in Switzerland.

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/mathmovies/

Comment: Does "Straw Dogs" count?

Comment: So, just documentaries about mathematicians, then?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: Isn't this question a dupe?

Comment: @TyquanPesik You may want to edit the question.  People might think you're asking about hermaphrodite mathematicians.

Comment: A person who allows himself to be deceived or deluded; one who is misled by false representations or notions; a victim of deception. Const. of, rarely to.

Comment: BTW, I opened MSE with a question in mind, the first question was this one, my mind automatically started playing: [You are, a cinema, I could watch you forever...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-KqDVNowKU&feature=youtube_gdata_player) - Now I forgot the question! Damn!

Comment: I'd like to watch "Colors of Math," but I don't know that it's available in America.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I'm lost...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/18843/1543

Answer (score 3):

I enjoyed [*N Is a Number: A Portrait of Paul Erdős*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125425/).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one. I liked it too.

Answer (score 2):

A few of my favorite documentaries are:

$\bullet$ *N is a Number - a Portrait of Paul Erdos*

$\bullet$ *Fermat's Last Theorem*

$\bullet$ *Taking the Long Road - the Life of Shiing-shen Chern*

$\bullet$ *I Want to be a Mathematician - A Conversation with Paul Halmos*

Comment: Yeah, all of Zala Films I've seen. Anything else?

Comment: I'm looking for something rare.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the Italian film "[La morte di un matemático napolitano](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morte_di_un_matematico_napoletano)"
([The death of a Neapolitan mathematician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_a_Neapolitan_Mathematician)) which is about the last days of Renato Caccioppoli.  This seems to fit your bill since he was a very important mathematician and lived a very eventful life but is hardly known outside of Italy. I have never managed to see the film but it is, apparently, of quite high quality.
By the way, it is a feature film, not a documentary.

Answer (score 2):

There is new movie called the man who knew infinity.It is about the famous number theorist Srinivasa Ramanujan Iyengar.

Answer (score 0):

The real man portrayed in A Beautiful Mind was not only an economist but a mathematician who published original discoveries in math. There is also a recent film bio of Alvin Turing. Sorry I forget the title.