# any Math game for kids?

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics, education

I need to plan a "game" for kids about 10-11 years old that involves mathematics and some physical activity or game.

It must be short-time and not very difficult because it's a stage of a big game.

Could anyone give me a good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: something like _the water jar_ problem, without the risk of pneumonia

Comment: Something I saw once... 10 kids or so stand in a circle facing inwards, joining hands.  Then they try to turn the circle inside-out (so they are facing outwards) without letting go of their hands.

Comment: The number 2 of that post, [Fun math outreach/social activities answer by Mike Spivey](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/18826/30049) , it's a good aproximation

Comment: and... the goal is do it without luxations ;) good idea, thaks a lot, something like that it's what I'm searching

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few suggestion:

1. The game of Nim: There are say 11 coins on the table. Two players. Players altrnate by taking between one and three coins per turn. The loser is the person who takes the last coin.
2. Connect 4. One person makes a move, the next person does, then the next... (includes everyone)
3. Bridgeit (google it)
4. Tic Tac Toe
5. Estimator game. Take a whole bunch of marbles or w/e and put them into a jar. Then get groups of kids to make a guess, one per kid, and then average the guesses for each group. The group that is closest to the true number wins. Then, after the win, take the average for all of the guessses and show them how much better it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is good idea to organize maths game so that children can improve their maths skills.
Here are some exciting mental math game:
 1. Estimation games: A popular estimation game involves two dices and paper. Two columns are supposed to made in which one has the value of dice and the other column can have numbers of choice. 
2. Math Jeopardy: In this activity, children are given a paper and a number is said to them. Children are supposed to find as many possible to make the number using addition, subtraction, multiplication and division
UCMAS also provide program related to maths where children can improve their maths skills.